# Would a magnetic field be affected permanently if it interacts with another magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

Would a magnetic field still be changed after it stops interacting with another magnetic field. As far as I know, a magnetic field is generated by spinning electrons. Thus, does a magnetic field affect the spin of the electrons?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know magnetic field can be changed by another field. Usually this takes alot of time. Magnetic field would not be changed after it stops interacting with another field. Magnetic field can affect the orientation of domains, and not the spin of electrons. Pardon me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just an extension of Jaskaran's answer, but the answer to your question is *yes* and here are some examples:

- if you stroke an unmagnetised piece of metal with a magnet then you can magnetise it (as demonstrated in elementary physics classes across the world!)
- if you expose magnetised metal to an oscillating magnetic field you can demagnetise it. This process [is used in demagnetisers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=demagnetizer).

As Jaskaran says, in both cases you are changing the relative alignment of the [magnetic domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) on the metal. In the first case applying the external field makes the magnetic domains line up to give an overall magnetic field. In the second case you are randomising the alignment of the domains to remove the magnetic field.